# R: how to define class serializers?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm looking for the R equivalent of Python's `__reduce__` for serialization and de-serialization of S3 classes - i.e. some method of manually specifying how to serialize and de-serialize objects which belong to a certain class.

Simple example:

Object creator:

```r
make_obj <- function(a = 1) {
    obj <- list(a = a, b = a + 1)
    class(obj) <- "myClass"
    return(obj)
}
```

Serializer and de-serializer:

```r
serializer <- function(obj) return(as.character(obj$a))

deserializer <- function(s) {
    a <- as.numeric(s)
    return(make_obj(a))
}
```

I see R has functions like `saveRDS` and `readRDS` which accept an argument `refhook` for customized serialization, and can be used with those two functions as intended:

```r
myObj <- make_obj(10)
saveRDS(myObj, "myObj.Rds", refhook = serializer)
newObj <- readRDS("myObj.Rds", refhook = deserializer)
```

But I'm looking for some way of making this automatic based on the object's class, so that (a) it would work with RStudio's save and restore session when those objects are in the environment, and so that (b) someone could just load a package and then use the internal R serialization functions without extra hassle.

I though of defining a custom `saveRDS.myClass` and registering it as an S3 method - e.g.:

```r
saveRDS.myClass <- function(obj, ...) {
    s <- serializer(obj)
    saveRDS(s, ...)
}
```

But this wouldn't work with RStudio's save session, and when calling `readRDS` it will not know that it should use the custom de-serialization function once it loads this object.

Is there any way of making these serialization and de-serialization functions be attached to an S3 class, so to say?